# Python watchdog does not log filesystem events

Tags: python, python-2.7, watchdog

I wrote the following piece of code to monitor the filesystem, using watchdog library:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler
from multiprocessing import Process
from pydispatch import dispatcher
import logging


class Watchman(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def start_watching(self):
        self.p = WatchDNSTask(self.path)
        self.p.start()

    def stop_watching(self):
        self.p.terminate()


class WatchDNSTask(Process):
    def __init__(self, path):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.path = path
        self.event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, path=path, recursive=False)

    def run(self):
        logging.info("Started monitoring {path}".format(path=self.path))
        self.observer.start()
        self.observer.join()
        logging.info("Stopped monitoring {path}".format(path=self.path))
```

But it won't log anything. I have been stuck on this for quite a while, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure logging. The default level is `WARNING`.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```